# Google Analtyics gTag

Tags: google-analytics

Is it correct way of implementing Google Analytics?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-000000- 00"></script>

<script>

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00');
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00', { 'anonymize_ip': true, 'forceSSL': true, 'anonymize_ip': true });
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00', {'page_title' : 'home', 'page_path': '/'});
```

Comment: Did it work? I'm happy to make changes to the answer if it's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documents it seems you are missing the "event" and have placed the values in the config.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-000000- 00"></script>

<script>

window.dataLayer =  window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00');
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00', {'metric1': 'anonymize_ip', 'metric2': 'forceSSL'});
gtag('config', 'UA-000000-00', {'metric3': 'page_title', 'metric4': 'page_path'});

gtag('event', 'send', {'anonymize_ip': true, 'forceSSL': true,'page_title': 'home', 'page_path': '/');
```

I deleted one of the duplicate `anonymize_ip`.